# how to use getElementById to check length

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm doing wrong?and maybe somebody tells me how to check length not bigger numbers not from keybord but buttons?

```
function checkLength() 
    {
    var input = document.getElementById("t") ;
     {
        if(input.value.length == 10)
        {
        input = input.replace(input, ''); 
        alert("Only 10 numers") ;
        }
    }
    }


<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" id="t" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkLength();" placeholder="Enter data" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "{}" left in your code, this code will work well:

```
function checkLength()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("t") ;
            if(input.value.length >= 10)
            {
                var value = input.value;
                input.value = value.slice(0,10);
                alert("Only 10 numers") ;

            }

    }
```

Comment: helped me but still whene I'm enetering some data from buttons it don't check

Comment: Sorry, I dont understood what you want do. Do you want validate if the value is a number and not a string?

Comment: If are using another form buttons to do some action, you will need create some fucntion to catch the event and call the function to validade length.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think input.replace is a function. If you just want to empty the input contents, I would suggest using `input.value = ""`.

Comment: And every time user type **a character** from blank, the JS prompts "Only 10 chars" and reject...It does not make sense. This checking should at lest be done when `onfocusout` isn't it? Removing previously typed value is also not a good idea at all though.

Answer (score 0):

function checkLength() 
    {

```
var input = document.getElementById("t") ;

    if(input.value.length > 10)
    {
    input.value="";
    alert("Only 10 numers") ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace is using for String elements, you just need add 'value' after input :)

```
input = input.value.replace(input, '');
```